# Template not displaying any data in Django application (Django 3.05)

Tags: python, django

Basically, I'm building a Django application that's like a blog. So, my "social" page is supposed to display posts (that right now I'm adding through the admin page). However, when I load that page, nothing shows up.

Here's my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Posts


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : Posts.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'social/social.html', context)
```

Here's my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Posts(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length = 20, help_text = 'Enter post title')
    post_text_content = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)

### Make seperate model for image content ###

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['post_title', 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_text_content']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'{self.first_name}, {self.last_name}, {self.user_name}')
```

Here's my `social.html`:

```
{% extends "social/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Your Feed</h1>
  <p>This is your feed. Here, you'll see posts from people you follow.</p>
  {% for post in Posts %}
    <h1>{{post_title}}</h1>
    <p>By {{post_author}}  on <i>{{post_date}}</i></p>
    <p>{{post_text_content}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

My `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>


    {% if title %}
    <title>WebNet - {{title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>WebNet</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

If I need to put any more files in, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo as pointed by Brenden. Also to access each value, you have to use the dot(.) operator inside the for loop. Try this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{ post.post_title }}</h1>
    <p>By {{ post.post_author }}  on <i>{{ post.post_date }}</i></p>
    <p>{{ post.post_text_content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here

```
{% for post in Posts %}
```

I think it should be

```
{% for post in posts %}
```